# Error: invalid address when I want send transaction

Tags: web3js

Trying to execute a contract function with web3 1.2.1. I have an Erc20 standard token.

```
mintCoin: function(amount, sender, callback) {

    console.log(contractInstance.options.address); //all good
    console.log(sender);

    contractInstance.methods.mint(amount, sender).send({from:sender})
        .then(() => callback("202"))
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            callback("400 " + e);
        });
}
```

> Error: invalid address (arg="account", coderType="address", value="50000")
>       at Object.throwError ...

I think I'm mistaken in the syntax... any help?

Comment: So what does `console.log(sender)` tell you?

Comment: It shows me the address that I pass through postman

Comment: Yeah I understand that part, but what does it actually show?

Comment: 0x1C3a56Ff8EE71304818E9E590E16F805048724f4
it gives me the value, it doesn't say undefined

Comment: And have you unlocked this account on the node side?

Comment: Nevermind that, I answered in an answer...

Comment: Mmm I think so, i'm working on locally blockchain, ganache
Otherwise how should i do it?

Comment: @goodvibration's answer seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `mint` takes `address to` as the 1st argument and `uint256 amount` as the 2nd argument.

You are passing them in reversed order (and web3 tells you that your amount is an invalid address).

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe it was that, I didn't realize

Comment: @AgusVelez: No problem.